# How does Nodejs cluster mode deal with HTTP keep-alive connections?

Tags: node.js, http, udp, cluster-computing

If the HTTP connection is keep-alive, does the same worker get stuck handling all the requests? I'd like to have a single HTTP server handling all the network traffic but handing off the data crunching of each request to a random worker process, even if those requests are coming in over the same HTTP (TCP) connection:

```js
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        worker.send(req, function(res) {
            // worker will generate response into callback parameter
            res.end();
        });
    }).listen(80);
}
else
{
    process.on('message', function(msg) {
          // generate an http reponse but DO NOT SEND IT OUT A SOCKET,
          // return it to Master
          var res = generate_http_response_object();
          process.send(res);
    });
}
```

Will that work?

Comment: So what's the result of investigation? :)